# How to pass object from jquery to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameter-passing

I wanna pass an object from jquery using a selector to a javascript function like below.

```
flash($("#something span"), "#fff", 250);
```

but it does not seem to be working.

and I am not sure what to put in the javascript function.
What I make now is:

```
function flash(obj,color1,color2,duration) {
    obj.animate({backgroundColor:color1},duration);
    setTimeout(function(){this.animate({backgroundColor:color2},duration);},duration);
}
```

or is there another way instead of passing an object? for example, in jquery:
    $("this").flash("#f79999", "#eee", 250);

but then how to define the javascript function?

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to include the [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin to animate properties like `background-color`.

From "[*Animation Properties and Values*](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties):"

> All animated properties should be animated to a *single numeric value*, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated **but `background-color` cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used**). [...]

---

> is there another way instead of passing an object? for example, in jquery: $("this").flash("#fff",250);

jQuery's [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) should help with this. But, you could define it as:

```
jQuery.fn.flash = function (color, duration) {
    return this.animate({ backgroundColor: color }, duration);
};

$('#something span').flash('#fff', 250);
```

Comment: yes I did, but I don't know how to define function in javascript.

Comment: @KyleXie The definition in your question should work fine with jQuery.Color included. For the `$(this).flash(...)` variant, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But there comes another issue. The function "setTimeout()" does not work inside the flash(). My flash method is to let the background to the a color, say red, and then turn back to the original color.
    flash() {
        this.animate({backgroundColor:to},duration);
 setTimeout(function(){this.animate({backgroundColor:from},250);},250);
    }
but the now only the first line runs while the second line does not.

Comment: @KyleXie Keep using `obj` rather than `this` inside the `setTimeout` function. You can also use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to chain animations: http://jsfiddle.net/UaY4j/

Comment: @KyleXie It's an issue of context. Every function has its own value for `this` and you have 2 functions -- `flash` itself and the anonymous function passed to `setTimeout`. To specify the value of `this` for the anonymous function, you can to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

Comment: That helps! But why can't I use setTimeout()?

Comment: @KyleXie You can. `.delay()` is just an alternative and [uses `setTimeout` itself](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.2/src/queue.js#L107). The likely issue was trying to use `this` inside the anonymous function. You'll need to use `bind`, `$.proxy`, or save `this` to a variable: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lb5w/

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple syntax error.

```
ojb.animate({backgroundColor:color},duration);
```

Should be

```
obj.animate({backgroundColor:color},duration);
```

Comment: Also, note that JQuery is a framework for javascript, so it is javascript.

Answer (score 0):

*With the [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin installed in the page (ack. @Jonathan Lonowski) ...*

You can avoid passing an object by using javascript's `.call()` or `.apply()`.

Here's an example :

```
$(function() {
    function flash(color, duration) {
        this.animate({backgroundColor:color}, duration);
    }
    $("#something span").on('click', function() {
        flash.call($(this), "#fff", 250);
    });
    $("#something_else span").on('click', function() {
        flash.apply($(this), ["#fff", 250]);
    });
});
```

`.call()` and `.apply()` aren't really necessary here; regular function calls would suffice.

`.call()` and `.apply()` are normally used in cases where you need to call a method of one object but give it the context of another object. By doing so, the method is made to operate on a different `this`.

Comment: Thank you both. But the setTimeout() method does not work inside the flash method, have any idea?

Comment: There was no setTimeout, you have edited it in! The simplest solution is not to use setTimeout but to use jQuery's [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), which is a chainable method that can be inserted into an animation sequence, `obj.animate(...).delay(...).animate(...);`.